# Echo linebreak to file using Phing on Windows

Tags: php, windows, file, line-breaks, phing

In my build script I'm trying to output the date and SVN revision number to a file in the build directory.  I would like the date and revision number on separate line, but can't get a linebreak to output to the file.  I've tried all sorts of methods:

```
    <echo file="${build.dir}\build.txt">DATE = ${DATE} \r\n \\\r\\\n PHP_EOL</echo>
    <echo msg="DATE: ${DATE} \r\n \\\r\\\n PHP_EOL 0x0D0A SVN revision: ${svn.lastrevision} . PHP_EOL" file="${build.dir}\build.txt" append="true" />
```

Has anyone else managed to get a linebreak through to file with Phing?  I've looked at the code in phing, and it uses fwrite.  I can only guess the strings in my build.xml are getting escaped in some way before being handled by fwrite?

I guess I may have to resort to using ExecTask?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make use of `${line.separator}`, see [Built-In Properties<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html#app.factsheet).

```
<echo msg="DATE: ${DATE}${line.separator}SVN revision: ${svn.lastrevision}${line.separator}" file="${build.dir}\build.txt" append="true" />
```

Comment: Very helpful! Can't even guess

Comment: @hakre, I tried the same in my case, where I have a here-document delimited EOF, but it is still not working. Could you please answer my question. I have an open bounty :)