# Unable to use here-document delimited by EOF within phing XML

Tags: xml, bash, heredoc, phing

I have some commands to be run after switching to a different user. I need to do this in a build xml file.

Following is what I have done -

```
<exec command="sudo su auto_deploy &lt;&lt; EOF
echo 'Logged in user'
whoami
EOF" dir="${dir.scratchpad}" />
```

I have used XML escaping, i.e. `&lt;` for `<`.

However, I am getting the following error -

```
sh: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

Related question - [here-document gives 'unexpected end of file' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660798/here-document-delimited-by-end-of-file)

**Update**

Note - I have not put any space after the starting EOF and before the ending EOF.

**Update 1**

Added bounty. Expecting an elaborate answer because I am unable to make much sense from the comments so far. Pardon my lack of knowledge.

**Update 2**

Just in case it was not clear, I am working on Phing, and the XML that I mentioned above is from the build xml file that Phing allows a user to write, to do deployment related stuff.

**Update 3**

As mentioned in the question referenced by @tripleee, I tried with this -

```
  <exec command="sudo su auto_deploy &lt;&lt; EOF${line.separator}echo 'Logged in user'${line.separator}whoami${line.separator}EOF" dir="${dir.scratchpad}" />
```

but it still throws the same error. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Syntax of here document: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells

Comment: remove the space replace by dash (as stated in the link): `sudo su auto_deploy &lt;&lt;-EOF`

Comment: I interpret the error message `here-document at line 0` as "I didn't get anything for input". Did you try removing the space, so you have `...&lt;EOF` ? Even if that fixes it, you may get a new error message. I'm skeptical (but will be happy to learn otherwise) that `<exec ...` can take a multiline input. Could you `echo "echo 'user'; whoami" |sudo ...` instead? Good luck.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I did that and got the same error.

Comment: @shellter I am skeptical about that too. I did not understand what you meant by the `|sudo` there.

Comment: Here-Docs send data to the reading process's std-in. So does `echo "xxx " | command`. But with the `sudo su` in the way, it's likely that won't work.  maybe `<exec command="sudo su \"echo 'logged in';whoami\" | auto_deploy...` ? Good luck.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How to save newlines in XML attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004386/how-to-save-newlines-in-xml-attribute). If the XML processor is normalizing the newlines to spaces, then the here document is being interpreted as a list of additional arguments to `sudo`, and so the terminating `EOF` is never found.

Comment: @chepner could you please elaborate that? I checked the other question, but am not getting what exactly is written there.

Comment: What program extracts the command from this `exec` element?  It looks like that's the one which isn't handling newlines correctly.  There is nothing in XML syntax specifically to define how exactly this should work; it's up to the tool to decide whether and if so how to process multi-line attributes.

Comment: @tripleee I am working on Phing, and the XML that I mentioned above is from the build xml file that Phing allows a user to write, to do deployment related stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995019/echo-linebreak-to-file-using-phing-on-windows

Comment: @tripleee, As mentioned in that question, I tried to do this, `<exec command="sudo su auto_deploy &lt;&lt; EOF${line.separator}echo 'Logged in user'${line.separator}whoami${line.separator}EOF" dir="${dir.scratchpad}" />` but it still throws the same error. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: @Sandeepan Have you tried `<exec command="sudo su auto_deploy &lt;&lt; EOF&#xA;echo 'Logged in user etc'" etc="etc." />`?

Comment: @Tomalak, no I didn't try that. You mean the `&#xA;` after the starting `EOF` and without any ending `EOF`?

Comment: I mean `&#xA;` (the encoded newline character) in every place that you want to have newline characters in your attribute value. Just like you use `&lt;` (the encoded left angle bracket character) in every place where you want to have a `<` in your attibute value.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used phing before, but looking at the documentation it looks like there are a couple of ways to solve your problem.  First, using the `-verbose` option it looks like your original solution might Just Work if you add an additional newline after the final `EOF`.  That is, if I have this `build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="chamilo" default="clean" basedir=".">
<target name="test">
<exec command="sudo -u deploy bash &lt;&lt;EOF${line.separator}echo Logged in user;whoami${line.separator}EOF" />
</target>
</project>
```

And I run `phing -verbose test`, I see:

```
     [exec] Executing command: sudo -u deploy bash <<EOF
echo Logged in user;whoami
EOF 2>&1
sh: line 2: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
     [exec] Logged in user
     [exec] deploy
     [exec] bash: line 2: EOF: command not found
```

Look at the final line of the generated script, which looks like:

```
EOF 2>&1
```

If I add an additional newline, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="chamilo" default="clean" basedir=".">
<target name="test">
<exec command="sudo -u deploy bash &lt;&lt;EOF${line.separator}echo Logged in user;whoami${line.separator}EOF${line.separator}" />
</target>
</project>
```

Then it Just Works:

```
     [exec] Executing command: sudo -u deploy bash <<EOF
echo Logged in user;whoami
EOF
 2>&1
     [exec] Logged in user
     [exec] deploy
```

Comment: Wow, the ending `${line.separator}` did the trick. Even the `-verbose` option was not necessary. You, Sir/Madam, deserve a medal! The bounty is definitely your. Need to wait for 20 hours.

Comment: Ohk now I understood why you used the verbose. The command written there works, but for showing some output, like echo output, `-verbose` is needed.

Comment: Right, I was using `-verbose` for the ability to see the generated script in order to better diagnose the problem.